# can i use multiple vim rc at difreent project

Tags: lua, neovim

##I am using neovim as my primary editor so it is possible to get the different project theme as the project also some extra features
'''
set exrc
'''
I know if you just insert this will work but it don't work at all

I want to get  vimrc as different project can i get that

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible as I have some example
but `exrc` want enough to get that thing

if you want to see how it work

`exrc` work with this files .exrc .vimrc
it works, but if you want to add at start time

you can see my [repo](https://github.com/AKrunal/.dotfile) for that

Comment: where to find?? it is in the nvim/localconfig/

Comment: change the link